# Why Bloom filter needs $\frac{m}{n}\ln{2}$ hash functions?

Tags: bloom-filters, hashing

I show from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Optimal_number_of_hash_functions) that the optimal number of hash functions is:

> $k =\frac{m}{n}\ln{2}$.

However it's not obvious for me why, even after reading the Wikipedia article (such as the one on false positives). Anyone interested in explaining with simple words? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in Wikipedia. Given $n,m$, the false positive probability is
$$
\left(1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{m}\right)^{kn}\right)^k.
$$
This is the quantity we want to minimize. While the exact expression is hard to minimize exactly, we can use the approximation
$$
\left(1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{m}\right)^{kn}\right)^k \approx (1-e^{-kn/m})^k,
$$
which is good if $m$ is large. We can optimize the latter expression using calculus, and the result is some expression which is very close to $(m/n) \ln 2$. This is a calculation that I leave to you.